# Flutter Stack Widget has Whitespace for some unknown reason

Tags: flutter

I'm still having trouble with Flutter's approach to laying out widgets.
There's this 'whitespace' that I would remove or cover (see red arrows).
How would I extend the 'image' up to the menu bar?

[image]

As you can see in the code below, I'm using a Stack widget.
I don't know what is making the 'whitespace' between the Stack widget and the appbar?? Possibly, it's due to the Crop widget (a third-party package). I'll look into that now, but decided to post this question anyway.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: I10n.t('Playhouse'),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 0,
        excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
      ),
      endDrawer: const ScrapBookDrawer(),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Crop(
            interactive: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            dimColor: Colors.white,
            controller: CropController(),
            child: Image.memory(
              base64.decode(
                con.submodule['image'],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          widget.subTask['subName'],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          'Submodule description',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                const Spacer(),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        color: Colors.white),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        /// Task Name and Number
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 30,
                            bottom: 20,
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            widget.subTask['name'],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 26,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                        /// Short Description or Title
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 10,
                          ),
                          child: Text(widget.subTask['short_description']),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        Flexible(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            child: Text(widget.subTask['long_description']),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is actually due to `Crop` widget. It automatically determines the aspect ratio of your picture. You should manually set your aspect ratio by adding the `aspectRatio` parameter to your `CropController`, something like this:

```
Crop(
  interactive: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  dimColor: Colors.white,
  controller: CropController(aspectRatio: 0.75),
  child: Image.memory(
    base64.decode(
      con.submodule['image'],
    ),
  ),
)
```

In your case it seems that aspect ratio of ~0.75 works the best, play around with this to find your best value.